# It is possible to have different storage capacity for different data nodes in cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

It is possible to add the nodes of different capacity to our Hadoop cluster.

Example:

```
Data Node 1 - 1 TB Disk space, 20 GB memory
Data Node 2 - 5 TB Disk space, 30 GB memory
Data Node 3 - 60 TB Disk space, 50 GB Memory.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But for this you need to different size of physical hard disk.

You can not define size of hard disk to use of data nodes in conf. File. So if you want your disk spaces to be of different size to be use in data nodes you can achieve this by having hard disk of different capacities.

However block size will remain same for all data nodes because block size is defined for whole cluster as same not for individual node.